# Get infos of submit button after a foreach

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I try to put some info into a new modal :

when I click on a button I want to open a new modal with good info of clicked pokemon.

I made controller :

```
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            #region ListeDesPokemons
            var pokemonList = new List<PokemonModel>();
            var Id = 1;
            var Img = 1;

            pokemonList.Add(new PokemonModel() { Id = Id++, Name = "Bulbizarre", UsName = "Bulbasaur(us)", JpName = "フシギダネ(jp)", Type1 = "Plante", Type2 = "Poison", Rate = 45, Image = "https://www.pokemontrash.com/pokedex/images/sugimori/00" + Img++ + ".png" });
            pokemonList.Add(new PokemonModel() { Id = Id++, Name = "Herbizarre", UsName = "Ivysaur(us)", JpName = "フシギソウ(jp)", Type1 = "Plante", Type2 = "Poison", Rate = 45, Image = "https://www.pokemontrash.com/pokedex/images/sugimori/00" + Img++ + ".png" });
var model = new PokemonViewModel();

            model.Pokemons = pokemonList;



            return View(model);
```

I made a Viewmodel :

```
     public List<PokemonModel> Pokemons { get; set; }

        public List<PokeBallModel> PokeBalls { get; set; }

        public List<PokemonStatutModel> PokemonStatuts { get; set; }
    }
```

I made a Model :

```
    public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string UsName { get; set; }

        public string JpName { get; set; }

        public string Type1 { get; set; }

        public string Type2 { get; set; }

        public int Rate { get; set; }

        public string Image { get; set; }
```

I made a view :

```
    @foreach (var pokemon in Model.Pokemons){ @pokemon.Id,@pokemon.Name @pokemon.Image}
```

here a picture of the first modal on the back of the screen with all pokemon list (foreach)
and the second modal on the front of the screen with no info.
please help.

[image]

Comment: "*here a picture of first modal on the back of the sreen with all pokemon list (foreach) and the second modal on the front of the screen with no infos*" this part is a bit confusing there is only (1) modal in the picture.

Comment: We will need to see what is in the rest of your view to help (.cshtml)

Comment: No loock more closer the first modal is the list of all pokemons and the second modal is the little "windows" with the sucess button (green)

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need to use form and should use ajax, when user click the picture of pokemon, you call an ajax with the Id of this pokemon, and in the controller you search all infos of pokemon with Id, and success in ajax just add infomations to the modal dialog. Something like:

```
<img class="align-self-center" id="tailleImg" src="@pokemon.Image" alt="@pokemon.Name" onclick="getInfo(@pokemon.Id)" />

    function getInfo(val)
{
    $.ajax({
        url: '/yourController/yourActionToGetInfo',
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        data: { "pokeId": val},
        success: function (data) {
                     $("#pokeId").val(data.Id);
                }

    })
}
```

Comment: Do I need to modify the controller I just beggin please help.

Comment: Yes, you should create a controller to get information and return data to ajax. If you don't know ajax, you can search example in google, it is easy to learn.

Comment: I made this but null value
[HttpPost]       
    public IActionResult Index(PokemonModel pokemon)
    {

        var pokemonName = pokemon.UsName;
        TempData["pokemonName"] = pokemonName;
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

Comment: the form in foreach you don't call url so it will null.

Comment: I don't know how to make a controller for get the information.

Comment: add action="/yourcontroller/Index" to form,
and the id should be the name of the pokemonviewmodel like: 
 <img class="align-self-center" id="Image" src="@pokemon.Image" alt="@pokemon.Name" />

Comment: I find :
in the controller :
[Route ("Pokedex/{PokemonId}")]
        public IActionResult PokemonDetails(int PokemonId)
        {

 

            int SelectedPokemonId = PokemonId;
            TempData["SelectedPokemonId"] = SelectedPokemonId;

 

            return PartialView("_PokemonDetails");
        }

But it's not ajax

Answer (score 0):

ok
In my view, in my foreach I add :

```
 @foreach (var pokemon in Model.Pokemons)
                {
                    <div class="col">
                        <button data-pokemon-id="@pokemon.Id" type="submit" class="btn" onclick="getInfo();">
                            <div class="card text-center rounded-lg">
                                <div id="tailleCard" class="card-body">
                                    <h5 id="cardTitle" class="card-title">n°@pokemon.Id <br /> @pokemon.Name</h5>
                                    <img id="tailleImg" src="@pokemon.Image" alt="@pokemon.Name" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </button>
                    </div>


                }
```

@ the end of the view I add : But the Request does not exist in the current context nedd help please.

```html
<script>

    function getInfo() {

        $.post('@(Url.Action("PokemonDetails", "Pokedex", null, Request.Url.Scheme))?pokemonId=' +
                $(this).data("pokemon-id"))
            .done(function (response) {

                

                $("#divContent").empty();
                $("#divContent").html(response);

                
                $("#divContent").html(response);
                $('#pokemonDetailsModal').modal('show');
                
            });

</script>
```

In the controller I add a :

```html
public IActionResult PokemonDetails(int pokemonId)
        {
            
            var model = new PokemonDetails();

            return PartialView("_PokemonDetails", model);
        }
```

I also made a Partial view _ and a PokemonDetail Model

```html
public class PokemonDetails
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

What I try to do it's to take the data of the selected pokemon (with the button in the foreach) and put the data of the selected pokemon in New Modal.

Answer (score 0):

OK i almost there ! cool

in the view

...

```html
@foreach (var pokemon in Model.Pokemons)
                    {
                    <button type="submit" class="btn" onclick="getInfo(@pokemon.Id)">
                        <div class="card text-center rounded-lg">
                            <div id="tailleCard" class="card-body">
                                <h5 id="cardTitle" class="card-title">n°@pokemon.Id <br /> @pokemon.Name</h5>
                                <img id="tailleImg" src="@pokemon.Image" alt="@pokemon.Name" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </button>
                    }
```

...

at the end of the view page :

```html
<script>
    function getInfo(val) {
        event.preventDefault;
        //debug log
        console.log('Star getInfo()');


        $.ajax({
            url: '/Pokedex/PokemonDetails/',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: "html",
            data: { "PokemonId": val },
            //data: json,
            //contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            success: function (response) {
                //debug log
                console.log(val);
                $("#pokemonDetails").html(response);
                $('#pokemonDetails').modal('show');
            }
        })

    }
</script>
```

in the controller :

```html
[HttpPost]
        public IActionResult PokemonDetails(int PokemonId)
        {

            int SelectedPokemonId = PokemonId;
            TempData["SelectedPokemonId"] = SelectedPokemonId;
            
           ToDoo : Get Info of the pokemon from the Id

            return PartialView("_PokemonDetails");
        }
```

How I can get the info of the selected pokemon from the selected Id???

https://i.stack.imgur.com/atajO.png

Answer (score 0):

```html
[HttpPost]
        public IActionResult PokemonDetails(int PokemonId)
        {

            int SelectedPokemonId = PokemonId;
            TempData["SelectedPokemonId"] = SelectedPokemonId;
            
           ToDoo : Get Info of the pokemon from the Id

            return PartialView("_PokemonDetails");
        }
```

Do you have database ? if you have just call:

```
return (db.PokemonModel.FirstOrDefault(n=>n.Id == PokemonId));
```

and if you don't have use the list you use in action Index:

```
return pokemonList.FirstOrDefault(n=>n.Id == PokemonId));
```

and in sucess ajax:

```
success: function (response) {

                $("#cardTitle").html("n°" + response.Id +"<br />" + response.Name");
                $("#tailleImg").attr('src', response.Image);
                $("#tailleImg").attr('name', response.Name);
                $('#pokemonDetails').modal('show');
            }
```

Comment: Go to this post to see where I am right now please. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58001231/find-data-with-id-from-httppost/58005967?noredirect=1#comment102420197_58005967

Comment: i'm a new biew here so i can't add comment in it, so i comment here: have you tried use TempData = pokemonlist without json, and use it in httpost ?

Comment: Answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58001231/find-data-with-id-from-httppost/58011634#58011634