# Find data with id from httpPost

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I made a HttpPost :

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult PokemonDetails(int PokemonId)
{

    return PartialView("_PokemonDetails");
}
```

I want to find all the data from the Id in the http.
the datas are in my controller :

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    #region ListeDesPokemons
    var pokemonList = new List<PokemonModel>();
    var Id = 1;
    var Img = 1;

    pokemonList.Add(new PokemonModel() { Id = Id++, Name = "Bulbizarre", UsName = "Bulbasaur(us)", JpName = "フシギダネ(jp)", Type1 = "Plante", Type2 = "Poison", Rate = 45, Image = "https://eternia.fr/public/media/pokedex/artworks/00" + Img++ + ".png" });
    pokemonList.Add(new PokemonModel() { Id = Id++, Name = "Herbizarre", UsName = "Ivysaur(us)", JpName = "フシギソウ(jp)", Type1 = "Plante", Type2 = "Poison", Rate = 45, Image = "https://eternia.fr/public/media/pokedex/artworks/00" + Img++ + ".png" });

    #endregion

    var model = new PokemonViewModel();

    model.Pokemons = pokemonList;

    ViewBag.TotalPokemon1G = pokemonList.Count;

    return View(model);
}
```

find good data from id thank you.
I do not have entity yet.

Comment: _" find good data from id "_  Do you mean to use id to get the data from  the `pokemonList ` that is populated in `Index` method ?  _" I do not have entity yet "_  Does it mean that you did not save the data in the `Index` method to the database? What is the logic between view and controller ? Could you share the more details on the view ?

Comment: Yes I have the Id of th selected Pokemon by a httpPost. My data are in the controller the data are not coming from A data base (sql)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `TempData` to pass data across different requests .[TempData](https://hassantariqblog.wordpress.com/2016/09/02/mvc-when-to-use-keep-vs-peek-in-asp-net-mvc/) is used to pass data from current request to subsequent request (means redirecting from one page to another). It’s life is very short and lies only till the target view is fully loaded. But you can persist data in TempData by calling Keep() method.

Here is a simple working demo

Model:

```
public class PokemonModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string UsName { get; set; }
    public string JpName { get; set; }
    public string Type1 { get; set; }
    public string Type2 { get; set; }
    public int Rate { get; set; }

    public string Image { get; set; }
}

public class PokemonViewModel
{
    public List<PokemonModel> Pokemons { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public IActionResult PokemonList()
    {
        #region ListeDesPokemons
        var pokemonList = new List<PokemonModel>();
        var Id = 1;
        var Img = 1;

        pokemonList.Add(new PokemonModel() { Id = Id++, Name = "Bulbizarre", UsName = "Bulbasaur(us)", JpName = "フシギダネ(jp)", Type1 = "Plante", Type2 = "Poison", Rate = 45, Image = "https://eternia.fr/public/media/pokedex/artworks/00" + Img++ + ".png" });
        pokemonList.Add(new PokemonModel() { Id = Id++, Name = "Herbizarre", UsName = "Ivysaur(us)", JpName = "フシギソウ(jp)", Type1 = "Plante", Type2 = "Poison", Rate = 45, Image = "https://eternia.fr/public/media/pokedex/artworks/00" + Img++ + ".png" });

        #endregion

        var model = new PokemonViewModel();

        model.Pokemons = pokemonList;
        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(pokemonList);
        TempData["pokemonJson"] = json;

        ViewBag.TotalPokemon1G = pokemonList.Count;

        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult PokemonDetails(int PokemonId)
    {
        var pokemonJson = TempData["pokemonJson"].ToString();
        TempData.Keep("pokemonJson");
        var pokemonList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<PokemonModel>>(pokemonJson);
        var pokemon = pokemonList.SingleOrDefault(p => p.Id == PokemonId);
        return PartialView("_PokemonDetails",pokemon);
    }
```

View:

```
@model WebApplication1.Models.PokemonViewModel


<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Pokemons[0].Name)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Pokemons[0].JpName)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Pokemons[0].UsName)
        </th>

        <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    @foreach (var item in Model.Pokemons)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>

                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.JpName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UsName)
            </td>
            <td>
                <input hidden  asp-for="@item.Id" />
                <a href="javascript:;" class="btnclick">PokemonDetails</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
  </tbody>
</table>

<div id="pokemon"></div>
@section Scripts{ 
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".btnclick").click(function () {
        var id = $(this).closest("td").find("input").val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "/Home/PokemonDetails?PokemonId=" + id,
            success: function (result) {
                $("#pokemon").html(result);
            }
        });
    });

</script>  
}
```

PartialView

```
@model WebApplication1.Models.PokemonModel
<div>
<hr />
<dl class="dl-horizontal">
    <dt>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Id)
    </dt>
    <dd>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Id)
    </dd>
    <dt>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
    </dt>
    <dd>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Name)
    </dd>
    <dt>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.JpName)
    </dt>
    <dd>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.JpName)
    </dd>
    <dt>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.UsName)
    </dt>
    <dd>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.UsName)
    </dd>
    <dt>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Type1)
    </dt>
    <dd>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Type1)
    </dd>
    <dt>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Type2)
    </dt>
    <dd>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Type2)
    </dd>
    <dt>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Rate)
    </dt>
    <dd>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Rate)
    </dd>
</dl>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you but is I put var = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(pokemonList).  This destroy my web site the design of it.

Comment: @AlexandreProd'Hon, this is just to save the `pokemonlist` to `TempData`. The model returned by your page is still the `PokemonViewModel`. It should not be affected. If there is the error message, could you share it?

Comment: This is my website with var json ...
https://ibb.co/McmTmg0   /////

and this is my website without var json ....
https://ibb.co/7n1FG0T

Comment: What is the design of the related views(Index view and partial view)? Did you press F12 to use browser developer tools to check if errors occurred?

Comment: this is when I use your code : 
https://ibb.co/3rQFCjd
////// The problem come only when I use TempData not var json = ...

Comment: The problem is the list stocked in TempData. When I remove this ligne everything go back to normal but I still cant access to PokemonList to my httpPost action...

Comment: I just saw on internet I get error 500 when trying to put a List in Tempdata.

Comment: @AlexandreProd'Hon , glad you resolve the issue.If you find my workaround is helpful , could you mark my reply as an answer ? Thanks a lot !

Comment: I don't know how to do it sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You can use LINQ to query the list for the Id you want.

```
int PokemonId = 2; // input from http post    
var result = pokemonList.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == PokemonId);
```

Comment: I cant acces to pokeList from action httpPost

Answer (score 0):

Ok I made it here is the answer.

My controller:

```c#
public IActionResult Index()
{
    #region ListeDesPokemons

    var pokemonList = new List<PokemonModel>();
    var Id = 1;
    var Img = 1;

    pokemonList.Add(new PokemonModel() { Id = Id++, Name = "Bulbizarre", UsName = "Bulbasaur(us)", JpName = "フシギダネ(jp)", Type1 = "Plante", Type2 = "Poison", Rate = 45, Image = "https://eternia.fr/public/media/pokedex/artworks/00" + Img++ + ".png" });
    pokemonList.Add(new PokemonModel() { Id = Id++, Name = "Herbizarre", UsName = "Ivysaur(us)", JpName = "フシギソウ(jp)", Type1 = "Plante", Type2 = "Poison", Rate = 45, Image = "https://eternia.fr/public/media/pokedex/artworks/00" + Img++ + ".png" });
     var model = new PokemonViewModel();

    model.Pokemons = pokemonList;

    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(pokemonList);

    TempData["pokemonListJson"] = json;
    TempData.Keep("PokemonListJson");

    ViewBag.TotalPokemon1G = pokemonList.Count;

    return View(model);
}


 [HttpPost]
public IActionResult PokemonDetails(int pokemonId)
{
    if (TempData["pokemonListJson"] != null)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(TempData["pokemonListJson"].ToString()))
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    var pokemonListJson = TempData["pokemonListJson"].ToString();
    TempData.Keep("PokemonListJson");

    var pokemonList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<PokemonModel>>(pokemonListJson);
    var selectedPokemon = pokemonList.SingleOrDefault(p => p.Id == pokemonId);

    if (selectedPokemon != null)
    {
        return PartialView("_PokemonDetails", selectedPokemon);
    }

    return null;
}
```

My partial View:

```cshtml
@model PokemonModel
<div id="taillDescriptionModal" class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-scrollable mw-100 m-auto" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 id="modalLabelStack2" class="modal-title font-weight-bold float-left">n° @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Id)</h5>
            <div id="nomPokemonStack2" class="ml-auto">
                <h5 id="Name">@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Name)</h5>  <h5 id="UsName">@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.UsName)</h5> <h5 id="JpName">@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.JpName)</h5>
            </div>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="close">
                <span class="text-danger" aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col overflow-hidden">
                    <img class="img-fluid rounded-lg" src="@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Image)" alt="pokemon.Name" />
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    <span>Type : </span>
                    <div class="col text-white">
                        <span class="@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Type1) badge">@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Type1)</span>
                        <span class="@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Type2) badge">@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Type2)</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Fermer</button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" onclick="afficheIdSurIndex(@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Rate))"> Choisir</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    function afficheIdSurIndex(selectedPokemonRate) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Pokedex/Calcul/',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: "html",
            data: { "selectedPokemonRate": selectedPokemonRate },
            success: function () {
                //enlever la classe pour afficher le contenu de la div
                $('#Test').removeClass('text-hide');
                //$('#Test').addClass('text-show');

                var rateTxt = 'Taux de Capture du pokémon sélectionné : ' + selectedPokemonRate
                //vider le contenu de la div
                $("#Test").empty();
                //écrire dans la div
                $("#Test").append(rateTxt);

                //fermer les modals
                $('#pokemonDetails').modal('hide');
                $('#choixPokemon').modal('hide');
            }
        })
    }
</script>
```

My Index page:

```cshtml
@model PokemonViewModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Pokedex";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutPokemon.cshtml";
    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>

}

<h1>Pokedex</h1>

<!-- Button choix Pokémon modal -->
<div class="container">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary mb-2" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#choixPokemon">
        Pokemon 1G
    </button>
</div>

<!-- Modal choix Pokémon -->
<div id="choixPokemon" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="choixPokemonModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div id="modalWitdh" class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-scrollable mw-100 m-auto" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 id="choixPokemonModalLabel" class="modal-title">Pokédex première génération, @ViewBag.TotalPokemon1G Pokémons </h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body text-center">
                <div class="row">
                    @foreach (var pokemon in Model.Pokemons)
                    {
                        <div class="col">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn" onclick="getInfo(@pokemon.Id)">
                                <div class="card text-center rounded-lg">
                                    <div id="tailleCard" class="card-body">
                                        <h5 id="cardTitle" class="card-title">n°@pokemon.Id <br /> @pokemon.Name</h5>
                                        <img id="tailleImg" src="@pokemon.Image" alt="@pokemon.Name" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    }
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Fermer</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Modal Description du pokémon choisi -->
<div id="pokemonDetails" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="descriptionPokemonModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    @*Contenue dans vu partiel _PokemonDetails*@
</div>

@*Div de collection des donnés du pokémon selectionné dans le deuxième modal.(données provenant de la vue partiel _PokemonDetails) *@
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        <h6 id="Test" class="text-hide"></h6>
    </div>
</div>

@*button script pour collecter les données du pokémon sélectionné dans le 1er modal*@
<script>
    function getInfo(pokemonId) {
        event.preventDefault;
        console.log(pokemonId);

        $.ajax({
            url: '/Pokedex/PokemonDetails/',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: "html",
            data: { "pokemonId": pokemonId },
            success: function (response) {

                $("#pokemonDetails").html(response);
                $('#pokemonDetails').modal('show');
            }
        })

    }
</script>
```

In the startup page I need to add:

```c#
services.AddMemoryCache();
services.AddSession();
services.AddMvc().AddSessionStateTempDataProvider();
```

I put everything here for help anyone who need help.

Answer (score 0):

add a breakpoint in action PokemonDetails:

```
[HttpPost]
        public IActionResult PokemonDetails(int pokemonId)
        { // add break point here
```

when the break point is hit here, did you get pokemonId ?

Comment: which lines do you change ?

Comment: A lot look I post an answer